# Any reliable way of debugging an iPad without Safari 6?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

We're developing a HTML5/JavaScript web-application that also runs on iPad. It has a few issues which none of the standard desktop browsers have and it seems impossible to debug.

When I read about remote debugging for iOS6 I thought I've found the solution, until I found out it can't be done with a Windows PC.

Now I wonder, how do you approach iPad issues without/prior to remote debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)?  If you can modify your hosted application without affecting any users, I'd definitely recommend it.